# How to download a complete html code with .html format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

HI I am creating a dynamic `html` section and I have two buttons: **preview** and **download**.

The **preview** is fine working. As for the second button, i.e. **download**, I want to make the action of the button such that if the **download** button is clicked, it triggers a download of all html code stored in the variable `rohit` with `.html` format.

How do I do this? Please let me know. I had searched for it on Google but could not find a way to do it.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var rohit = "<h2>Hello i m Dynamic Heading </h2>";
     $('.preview').on('click', function(){
            var myWindow = window.open('', "rohit", "width=800, height=400", '_blank');
   myWindow.document.write(rohit);
        });
    
    
     $('.download').on('click', function(){
         alert(rohit);
            //  here download code with html format how to do this .
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="preview">click to preview</button>
<button class="download">CLick to Download</button>
```

and **Jsfiddle** **[Link here](http://jsfiddle.net/9n5v8m26/)**

Comment: Is the html file saved in your server?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-not-through-server

Comment: no it saved to local

Comment: Thanks mr. @Raghavendra My problum is  solve to this url you ping me in chat thanks for this ..

Answer (score 1):

In short: you need to use `Blob`.

For more info and demo:
 [Save/download data generated in JavaScript](http://hackworthy.blogspot.co.il/2012/05/savedownload-data-generated-in.html).
 [Demo](http://web.student.tuwien.ac.at/~e0427417/jsdownload.html).

Answer (score 1):

Most likely what you have to do is to change the headers of you request to be:

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.html"
```

That will tell the browser to download your file.